# Rails 5 left_outer_join with specific saved ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, left-join

I have a system with the following models

```
class Application < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :offers, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :accepted_offer, class_name: 'Offer', 
                              foreign_key: 'accepted_offer_id',
                              optional: true
```

```
class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :application
```

and was creating a report that gathers all the offers by `accepted_offer_id` like thus

```
Application.find_each do |app|
  offer = Offer.find(app.accepted_offer_id) if app.accepted_offer_id
  report.push(report_body(app, offer))
end
```

This is becoming too slow, I would like to rewrite the report bit so that it leverages a left join to make the connection with a sinle query to the db.

I would like to have the query return all offers that are stored as `accepted_offer_id` on the applications table.

```
Offer.left_outer_joins(:applications).where(id: { 'application.accetped_offer_id' })
```

I know the above is wrong but I am sure it must be possible to get the collection with a single query?

Comment: Try `.where("application.accetped_offer_id IS NOT NULL")`

Answer (score 2):

Anything like this?

```
class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :application

  scope :accepted, -> { joins(:application).where('offers.id = applications.accepted_offer_id') } 
end

Offer.accepted
```

Comment: Not sure what the schema is here but this will only work if `offers.application_id = application.id` AND `offers.id = applications.accepted_offer_id` because of the join. If these 2 are separate concerns then this query will fail e.g. if an applications.accepted_offer_id can be for an offer associated with a different application

Comment: Yes, I know, but this should work for how I intended the schema

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite the first bit a bit nicer:

```
Application.find_each do |app|
  report.push(report_body(app, app.accepted_offer)) if app.accepted_offer
end
```

Moving onto rewriting the SQL, I'm pretty sure what you need to do is:

```
Offer.joins(:application).where('offers.id = applications.accepted_offer_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also choose to use a sub-query.

```rb
offer_ids = Application.select(:accepted_offer_id)
offers = Offer.where(id: offer_ids)
```

Should result in (MySQL):

```sql
SELECT `offers`.*
FROM `offers`
WHERE `offers`.`id` IN (
  SELECT `applications`.`accepted_offer_id`
  FROM `applications`
)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the `#inspect` method already triggers the query (with a limit of 11). This is only a problem if you copy it into the Rails console. To prevent this suffix the lines with `;nil`. This way the result is not returned to the console, which in turn would call the `#inspect` method. Alternatively you could wrap this into a `begin`/`end` block.